# Existence of weak limit of measures

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $\{\mu_n\}$ is a sequence of Borel probability measures on $\mathbb{C}$ such that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int fd\mu_n
$$

exists for all $f \in C_b(\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{R})$. Is it true that there exists a measure $\mu$ such that

$$
\int f d\mu = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int fd\mu_n?
$$

In other words, is there a measure $\mu$ such that $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly?

In my problem, we can assume the support of the $\mu_n$ is contained in the unit ball, if it helps.

Comment: The answers below are right, but another thing you might care about is whether the resulting $\mu$ is actually a probability measure. In general, it doesn't have to be (imagine $\mu_n$ spreading out to infinity, like a uniform distribution on the ball of radius $n$), but in your case it actually is, by just taking $f$ to be any continuous function with compact support that is $1$ on the unit ball.

Comment: It seems like either the answers below are not entirely correct or @J.G, your comment is not correct. If $\mu$ is as desired in the question, then, choosing $f = 1_{\mathbb{C}} \in C_b$ yields $\mu(\mathbb{C}) =$ lim $\int f d\mu_n = 1$.

Comment: I guess the question is: Does $\int f d\mu =$ lim$\int f d\mu_n$ hold for $f \in C_b$ or merely for $f \in C_c$? In the first case, $\mu$ should be a probability measure, see my comment above. If only the latter holds, the initial question is not answered affirmatively. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! Consider the restriction to the space of continuous functions with compact support, denoted by $C_{c}(\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{R})$. Now define $$L(f):= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int f \, d\mu_{n}\qquad , \, f\in C_{c}(\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{R}).$$

It is straightforward to check that $L$ defines a bounded linear functional on $C_{c}(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{R})$. Indeed, since the $\left\{\mu_{n}\right\}$'s are Borel probability measures on $\mathbb{C}$, we have

$$\lvert L(f) \rvert \leq \lvert \lvert f\rvert \rvert_{\infty}$$ Hence by the Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem, there exists a unique Borel measure $\mu$,with total variation-norm less than 1, such that $$L(f) = \int f \, d\mu \qquad \forall f\in C_{c}(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{R}).$$
In fact, the integral is well-defined for all $C_{b}(\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{R})$ as well.

Comment: Does the representation of $\mu$ extend to $C_b$-functions as well? If not, then this does not completely answer the question, does it?

Comment: @Marco As i mentioned yes, since all the measures are finite. Am I missing something?

Comment: Clearly, $\int f d\mu$ is well-def. for each $f \in C_b$. But does it hold $\int f d\mu = L(f)$ for all $f \in C_b$? If so, then the above comment that $\mu$ need not be a probability measure seems wrong, because in this case we may choose $f = 1_{\mathbb{C}}$ to obtain $\mu(\mathbb{C})=1$ or am I wrong?

Comment: @Marco It is a probability measure, just as J. G says....

Comment: Of course I meant in the general case, without assuming the $\mu_n$ to have a common compact support

Comment: Where are we assuming that the measures have a common compact support?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, in the original question it says that one may assume each $\mu_n$ to have support in the unit ball and J.G points out that this is needed to conclude that the mass of $\mu$ is $1$. What am I missing out on?

Comment: You are mistanken. He is commeting "\mu"

Comment: Could you be so kind to point out my mistake to me? To me this sounds like one could conclude that $\mu$ is a probability measure in the above situation by only assuming the convergence of $\int f d\mu_n$ for each $f \in C_c$. However, I do not see how this really follows. I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: I thought one could only conclude that $\mu$ is a subprobability measure, since we only know its total variation norm is less or equal to $1$, but not necessarily equal to $1$.

Comment: The initial assumption that the limit exists for all bounded continuous functions is key, to conclude that the limiting measure is a probability measure. If the assumption only holds for compactly supported functions, then you might not get a probability measure, like J. G suggests.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. Is there, by any means, a chance to reduce the assumption on the existence of the limit to some countable set of functions? Since $C_b$ is not separable and since $C_c$-functions are not sufficient, this seems not immediate. I would appreciate ideas on this!

Comment: However, if the existence of the limit is only known for $C_c$-functions, the resulting limit measure will always be a sub-probability measure. Is this correct?

Comment: If by sub-probability measure, you are refering to a positive measure with total variation norm no bigger than 1, then yes. Right off the bat, whenever your class of functions include integrable functions, you will not preserve probability measures under weak*limits. I don't know what you are trying to accomplish, so you have to specify that by creating a new thread.

Comment: Concerning sub-probability measure: Yes, this is what I was asking for; a non-negative Borel measure with total mass $\leq 1$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "whenever your class of functions include integrable functions"? Any $C_c$- (or $C_b$) is integrable w.r.t. any finite measure, certainly I misunderstand you on this one? By the way, thanks a lot for your communication on this!

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify my simple observations. Whenever your class of functions is contained in the set of integrable functions w.r.t the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{C}$, then weak*-limits of probability measures won't get preserved. This follows by taking $\mu_{n}$ to be any family of normalized indicator functions of exhausting subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ and apply the dominated convergence theorem, to conclude that the weak*- limit measure is 0. However if your class contains functions which constant on the support of the limiting measure then you will preserve it.

Answer (score 3):

Define $l: C_c(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ by $l(f) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int fd\mu_n$. Then $l$ is a positive, continuous linear functional, so by Riesz representation theorem, there is some measure $\mu$ with $l(f) = \int fd\mu$.