# Existence of limits of integrals w.r.t. sequence of measures implies existence of weak* limit

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a Polish space. Let $(\mu_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of Borel probability measures on $X$.

Assume that for every continuous bounded function $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$, the limit $L(f) := \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_X f d \mu_n$ exists.

Does it follow that there exists a Borel probability measure $\mu$ such that $L(f) = \int_X f d \mu$ ?

I've found a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3320495/existence-of-weak-limit-of-measures) which about $X = \mathbb{C}$. There we can use Riesz-Kakutani representation theorem, since $\mathbb{C}$ is locally compact, but for arbitary Polish space $X$ this doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

**Theorem:** $\mu$ exists if and only if $\{\mu_n\}$ is [tight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tightness_of_measures).

$"\Rightarrow"$: Straightforward by [Prohorov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prokhorov%27s_theorem).

$"\Leftarrow"$: When there is no appropriate additional structure on the measurable space, [Daniel integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniell_integral) is the most abstract way to construct a measure, as far as I know. It's suffice to show $f_n\downarrow 0\Rightarrow L(f_n)\downarrow 0$. Tightness together with [Dini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem) will help you finish the proof.

Comment: Thanks! However this raises another problem: does there exist a sequence $( \mu_n )$ such that the limits $L(f)$ from the initial question exist, but the collection $\{\mu_n\}$ is not tight? I suspect yes, but I'm unable to give an example.

Comment: @djmati11 you're right. I'll look into it.